# Advice for running Linux Virtual Machine on Windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, virtual-machine

I have a python application that I am currently operating in Windows (because I need to be able to send TCP commands to a 3rd party Windows application which is running on the same machine). However, I want to be able to use libgphoto2, which generally only runs on Linux machines. Is it possible to set up a virtual machine and run everything from a single computer? My Python scripts can currently be run from either Linux or Windows. An easy way to do this would be to have one computer with Windows which I control over TCP from a secondary computer running Linux...but this means that I will need 2 computers.

Any advice?

Comment: Not sure this question is on topic for SO since it's not really related to programming per se...

Comment: Virtual machines provide TCP networking too. Should be no problem running everything on one computer.

Answer (score 2):

Light solutions, just a Linux compatibility layer:

- [latest Windows has native Linux support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about)
- for older Windows versions, [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)
- or [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/)

If it doesn't work, you can resort to a real virtualization, e.g.  VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

Try VM Player.

Where you can setup linux over windows and communicate between virtual linux and windows host.

[VM Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/playerpro-evaluation.html)